# Replacing compressor motor (going from 3 wire to 4 wire) and question about wire colors

Tags: air-conditioning, fans, compressor

I am replacing a GE motor with an equivalent Mars motor, they are same fitting size, HP, RPM etc. and volt range 208-230.  The wires are different though:

1. The old motor had orange, blue, and black
2. The new motor has `four` wires, brown, brown/white, yellow and black.

the black and yellow have raw tips, and the brown and brown/white wires have female knife-blade connections.

I am wondering which wires to equivalently hook up. I'm thinking obviously the black is common, but beyond that I don't know.

[image: old motor]
[image: orange and blue connection to - capacitor maybe?]
[image: black connection to terminal (in back)]
[image: new motor label]
[image: new motor diagram]
[image: new motor wire ends shown]

Comment: Can you include a better photo of the wiring diagram on the new motor?  Typically, Brown and Brown/White go to the run capacitor. Black and Yellow are line (L1 and L2)

Comment: See answer I posted below - yes, you're correct on both and old motor is in trash.  But answer below also clarifies what I didn't understand about the 4 vs. 3 wire setup and why the change.

Comment: It doesn't hurt to swap the cap.  Capacitors have a finite service life, and "wear" both in service and in storage.  A well tended motor can run indefinitely, especially an induction motor.

Comment: what does line mean? i have the motor you had, does orange and black both go to hot if so is there a neutral? or is orange neutral and black hot or vise versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out!  I hope this answer posted here helps someone else.  The real topic here is "converting from a 3 to 4 wire motor.

First of all, a shout out to Solar Supply, Inc. in San Marcos, TX for matching the Mars 10204 motor with my GE for about 85 bucks.

The first thing he did when I got it was grab a capacitor and add it to the box.  I thought, "I wonder why, I already have one?"  Well, now that I compared both diagrams it makes sense.

The old motor's orange line was connected to one of 3 leads on the capacitor.  From that line I noticed that there was a YELLOW line that went to the terminal block.  I deduced that orange was analogous to yellow on the new motor.  Black? That was easy, at least one thing was obvious.

That leaves the brown and brown/white pair.  It finally dawned on me that these were to go on the `new, separate` capacitor that the guy at Solar gave me.  I'm assuming that having a dedicated capacitor for the fan motor is an overall improvement in safety and integrity.  I suppose it would be theoretically possible to join the brown and brown/white wires to the old capacitor, but Murphy's law said that a 50% chance of getting it wrong is optimistic..  by so doing you're essentially joining one leg of the capacitor wires to the line voltage, and there must be a good reason why the capacitor is now separate.

The small green ground wire was a bit of a mystery but I just added it to the mount screw attaching the motor to the grill.  Here is the diagram which should make everything clear:

[image: old vs. new comparison]